# Hangul Jamo: what is the correct print-width of characters in the range of 0x1160 .. 0x11ff?

Tags: unicode, character

Is there a place in the Unicode documentation which states that characters in the range of `0x1160 .. 0x11ff` (a part of Hangul Jamo) should be treated as zero-width characters?
Most terminal emulators I have tried treat these characters as zero-width characters, but a few terminal emulators treat them as one-width characters.

Comment: If I understand this text correctly, there is a de jure standard and a de facto standard: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201009-00/?p=104351